# qt-creator will not install

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, programming, qt-creator

I tried to install qt creator from both app grid, software-center, and gnome-software. All 3 yielded an error similar to this error:

[image: error message from software-center]

I expanded the "details" section and got this output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

qtcreator: Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls (>= 5.2.1-4~) but 5.5.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed       
Depends: qml-module-qtquick2 (>= 5.2.1-5~) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is to be installed       
Depends: qtcreator-data (= 3.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2) but 3.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2 is to be installed  
Depends: libclang1-3.6 (>= 3.6) but 1:3.6.2-3ubuntu2 is to be installed   
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5concurrent5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5designer5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1-3build1 is to be installed   
Depends: libqt5designercomponents5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1-3build1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.5.0) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu6 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5help5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1-3build1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.5.0) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0~rc1) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5quickwidgets5-gles (>= 5.5.1-2ubuntu1~xenial1~test2) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5sql5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5test5 (>= 5.5.0) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5webkit5 (>= 5.2.0) but 5.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.3.0) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt5xml5 (>= 5.2.0) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2 is to be installed
Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is a virtual package
Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is a virtual package
```

This computer is running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus.

Sorry that I don't know how to add code for all these lines, it only seems to want to do one line, feel free to edit with code corrected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your system upgraded or newly installed 16.04?

Comment: @anwar My system is up to date.

Comment: You installed 14.04 then upgraded or installed 16.04

Comment: @anwar no, I started with 16.04. Never had 14.04 on this machine. Newer laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository apparently has something broken. I however found that the .run file from their website https://wiki.qt.io/Main works without any problems. Simply download, cd to Downloads in terminal, and run:

```
chmod +x qt-unified-linux*
./unified-linux... [tab to autocomplete filename]
```

Works without a glitch!